# Dynamic grid: add more columns when screen size grows

Tags: css

I am trying to make a grid in which columns dynamically adapt to the screen size. The most important criteria is that I want just 1 column on mobile devices or browsers on pc with similar dimensions, more columns can be added when the browser window grows in width.

I have been using a grid to implement this:

```
.App {
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  justify-items: stretch;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(?, ?)); /* Should change */
}
```

All the content in the grid have same width and look like the following sketched out:
[image]
For the specific width of the children of the grid, I was thinking about the `minmax` function to decide whether it should just fill the full viewport width or not, but I hit a rock there. Because if I use something like `minmax(25vw, 100vw)` then I'd always have a width of `100vw` because nothing is preventing it from not being full width.

I am not a css guy and don't have too much experience with it so if I said something completely stupid, don't hesitate to point it out!

Comment: Genuinely curious to know if my answer below was helpful for you or not?

Comment: @luke-codewalker Hi Luke, sorry to keep you waiting! I haven't had the time to try it out, but I sure will upvote it and mark it as correct when I gave your solution a go!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, then [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) should be the solution to your problem. They allow you to specify *rules that only apply for certain screen sizes* (or other conditions).

In your case let's assume you want one column on all devices that have a maximum width of `720px` and if they are larger just fit as many columns in the grid as possible (correct me if I'm wrong!).

Then we could use this for all small screens:

```
@media (max-width: 720px) {
  .grid {
      grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 720px);
  }
}
```

and use `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 200px);` where `200px` is the width of our items for example for all other cases.

See below for an example:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.grid {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 200px);
}

.item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background-color: #aaa;
}

@media (max-width: 720px) {
  .grid {
      grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 720px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

**Note:** use "Full Page" to see it working with a larger `width`.